# Start while loop in one multiprocessing function, from another multiprocessing function

Tags: python, while-loop, multiprocessing

So I want to **start a nested while loop in one multiprocessing function from another multiprocessing function**. In one function, I'm changing a variable (`action`) to `"fn2"`, and in the other function there is a nested while loop whose condition is `while action == "fn2":`.

See code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

running = True
action = None


def func1():
    global action
    if 1+1 == 2:
        action = "fn2"
        print(action)


def func2():
    while running:
        while action == "fn2":
            print("fn2")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

However, when I run it, the code just prints `"fn2"` once (confirming that `action` is equal to `"fn2"`). But the nested loop inside `func2()` does not execute. Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm new to multiprocessing.

Comment: running and action are not shared

Comment: @ToTamire can you explain that as an answer. Sorry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: Each process is running in its own address space and therefore has its own copies of global variables. When `func1` modifies `action`, it is not the same global `action` that `func2` sees when running in a separate process. That is, these two variables `running` and `action` are not shared between processes.  See [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=value#multiprocessing.Value), for example, that could be passed as an argument to both processes.

Comment: Besides that, you have a "race condition". If `func2` executes before `func1` (you do not have control over how the two processes you create get dispatched), then it will never see `action == "fn2"` and it will still never print even once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i added two comments (with `print` statements) to highlight the error.

basically `action=None` in `func2()` so that is why...

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

running = True
action = None


def func1():
    global action
    if 1+1 == 2:
        action = "fn2"
        print(action)


def func2():
    while running:
        print('got here')  # <--- loops infinitly here
        print(action) # <--- this is none
        while action == "fn2":
            print("fn2")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=func2)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

In order to share values when multiprocessing, which is called `Sharing state between processes` you need to use `value` or `array` for a single device shared memory or alternatively, `Manager` for networks of servers.

Here is a link:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

The basic format looks like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

So in the case of the question what the variable `action` is equivalent to `n` (variable) or `a` (list) etc.. and this can be shares across functions.

Also note that one can parse arguments into multiprocess functions with the `args` keyword: `args=(num, arr ...)`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I know what the error is (and why it is happening thanks to the comments) could you show me how to fix it?

Comment: Yes,  this is known as `Sharing state between processes`. There are two options to do this [1] `Shared memory` (for a single computer) and [2]  `Server process` (across servers). I will add comments to this to the answer.